# Is there a built-in list of culture name constants?

Tags: c#, cultureinfo

So I can't for example set the default to english, like so

```
CultureInfo MyCulture =  CultureInfo.ENGLISH;
```

or

```
CultureInfo MyCulture =  CultureInfo.getCultureInfo(CulureInfo.Eng);
```

I have to introduce a string dependency, using a list [I found on the internet](http://timtrott.co.uk/culture-codes/) (or create my own enum) :

```
CultureInfo MyCulture =  CultureInfo.getCultureInfo("en-AU");
```

So is there already an enum or other kind of list of all available `CultureInfos`?

Comment: Whats your question? There doesn't really need to be a built in list IMO, unless you wish to give the user the option to change it

Comment: What's the question? Is there a built in list of cultures?

Comment: duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5726905/why-isnt-there-a-culture-enum

Comment: As far as I know there is no such enumeration, but it would be very kind of you to create such a class and post it here.

Comment: You should use the magic constant `"en-AU"`. However you can search the installed cultures, for example (using Linq): `var yourCulture = CultureInfo.GetCultures(CultureTypes.SpecificCultures).First(c => c.DisplayName.Contains("Australia"));`.

Comment: The problem is that every computer has a different list of installed cultures.

Comment: @TimSchmelter ok, I want a list of iso languages in c#. Java has locale, which is iso compatible

Comment: @NimChimpsky Do you want `CultureInfo.GetCultures(CultureTypes.SpecificCultures).Select(c=>c.Name)`? Or some perhaps with another type like `AllCultures` or `NeutralCultures`?

Comment: @CodesInChaos no, I'll answer my own question in a bit

Answer (score 3):

You can obtain iso languages and region names, using System.Globalization classes:

```
System.Globalization.CultureInfo[] cinfo = System.Globalization.CultureInfo.GetCultures(System.Globalization.CultureTypes.AllCultures & ~System.Globalization.CultureTypes.NeutralCultures);
System.Globalization.RegionInfo ri = null;
foreach (System.Globalization.CultureInfo cul in cinfo)
{   
    try
    {
        ri = new System.Globalization.RegionInfo(cul.Name);
        Console.WriteLine(cul.TwoLetterISOLanguageName+"-"+ri.TwoLetterISORegionName);
    }
    catch(ArgumentException)
    {
        continue;
    }
}
```

Comment: Seeing a "catch all" always makes me cringe, even in sample code (that gets copy and pasted into prod code much too often, BTW). Please consider to only catch `ArgumentException` as documented by MSDN.

Comment: Why do you want to try to create the `RegionInfo` instance? You already have the format `[languagecode]-[CountryCode]` in your `cul.Name` or `cul.ToString()`, so just write that out. Note: You explicitly took away the neutral cultures which do not have the country-code part.